# Getting inherited variables

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm still relatively new to C#.NET so I'm sure that there is something obvious that I'm missing but here it is: I'm having trouble getting some variables out of a particular class.

The class in question looks like this:

```
class AridPlanet : Arid
    {
        public const int area = 95;

    }
```

As you can see this class inherits from the following class:

```
abstract class Arid : Astro
    {
        public const int metal = 2;
        public const int gas = 2;
        public const int crystals = 0;
        public const int fertility = 5;

    }
```

Which in turn inherits from the following class:

```
abstract class Astro
    {
        public int metal;
        public int gas;
        public int crystals;
        public int fertility;
        public int area;

    }
```

I attempt to get the variables in the following:

```
class Base
    {
        private int metal;
        private int gas;
        private int crystals;
        private int fertility;
        private int area;
        private List<Structure> structures = new List<Structure>();
        private int position;
        private Astro selectedAstro;

        public Base(Astro astro, int position)
        {
            this.selectedAstro = astro;
            this.metal = selectedAstro.metal;
            this.gas = selectedAstro.gas;
            this.crystals = selectedAstro.crystals;
            this.fertility = selectedAstro.fertility;
            this.area = selectedAstro.area;
            this.position = position;

        //Code ommited
    }
    }
```

The `astro` parameter is passed to the `Base` constructor as a specific astro type, for example `AridMoon`.

When I run the code to see what the `Base` variables are assigned to I see that they are all assigned to 0. To me, this suggests that the code is trying to assign the variables from the top most superclass of `AridPlanet` which is `Astro`.

However, as I understood inheritance, the compiler should look at the class indicated first before moving on to superclasses.

Any thoughts on what is going wrong? I'm sure that it's something simple that I've misunderstood.

Comment: constants aren't variables (or fields - that would be the correct terminology).

Comment: You might want to look at your compiler warnings...

Comment: Of course, they don't change so constants make sense, or perhaps `readonly` I'm not entirely sure of the difference. In either case, I'm having trouble getting the values and assigning them.

Comment: Compiler says: `Warning 1 'AEBaseCalcCSharp.GaiaMoon.area' hides inherited member 'AEBaseCalcCSharp.Astro.area'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.` Not entirely sure what this is telling me though, can anyone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reference *Astro astro*, you will in fact get the constants as defined in *Astro*.  You would have to cast it to a specific subclass to get the constants defined in that subclass.

What you are probably looking for is virtual properties.

You can define

```
abstract class Base 
{
    abstract public int Metal { get; }
}
```

Then you can implement that abstract method in a subclass

```
public class AridPlanet : Base
{
    const int ARID_PLANET_METAL = 2;
    public override int Metal { get { return ARID_PLANET_METAL; } }
}
```

I skipped over intermediate levels of your hierarchy, but hopefully it illustrates the point.  Intermediate classes can override the abstract definition.  Their subclasses can optionally supply an additional override or accept the one from the intermediate class.

Comment: @Jagannath abstract implies virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Let me use an example here to illustrate what you do:

- Create a class "Car" and define some properties a car must have
- Create a class "Sportscar", that extends the "Car"-class and assign values to the properties
- Use an instance of class "Car" an wonder why it does not know about the Sportscar.

It looks as if you were looking to use polymorphism. Use an interface or abstract class (as Eric showed) as base class that determines what information and capability each derived class must have. When you create a new instance of your subtype you can store it as the type your interface is and all calls to the instance will be delegated to the subclass. The important part is, which constructor you call.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you should do:

```cs
class AridPlanet : Arid
{
    public AridPlanet()
    {
        area = 95;
    }
}

abstract class Arid : Astro
{
    public Arid()
    {
        metal = 2;
        gas = 2;
        crystals = 0;
        fertility = 5;
    }

}
```

Then change the **Astro** class fields access modifier to **protected** and create respective **readonly properties** with **public** access.

**EDIT:**

```cs
abstract class Astro
{
    protected int metal;
    protected int gas;
    protected int crystals;
    protected int fertility;
    protected int area;

    public int Metal { get { return metal; } }
    public int Gas { get { return gas; } }
    public int Crystals { get { return crystals; } }
    public int Fertility { get { return fertility; } }
    public int Area { get { return area; } }
}

class BaseCalc
{
    private int metal;
    private int gas;
    private int crystals;
    private int fertility;
    private int area;
    //private List<Structure> structures = new List<Structure>();
    private int position;
    private Astro selectedAstro;

    public BaseCalc(Astro astro, int position)
    {
        this.selectedAstro = astro;
        this.metal = selectedAstro.Metal;
        this.gas = selectedAstro.Gas;
        this.crystals = selectedAstro.Crystals;
        this.fertility = selectedAstro.Fertility;
        this.area = selectedAstro.Area;
        this.position = position;

        //Code ommited
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "create respective readonly properties with public access" since the protected fields wouldn't be accessible by the `Base` class. But apart from that, your answer suggests that the program is looking in Astro first rather than the subclass I indicate. As I say above, this is not how I understand inheritance to work.

Comment: I have edited the answer. There are a lot of examples out there if you want to learn how inheritance work. Here is the link to inheritance explaination at msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx